# Setting up a message box for cookies

Tags: cookies

Hi there I need some help about setting up a a message box that tells viewers that my site uses cookies, This is due to the new EU law about having to ask their permission to save cookies.
I have never manually set up cookies before and I'm having difficulty finding exactly what I want/need.

Basically when the viewer first looks at the site there is a box at the top which explains that the site uses cookies, they can either view what the cookies do, accept or not accept.

I have the box already in place what I need now is a script that if the viewer clicks Yes and accepts then a cookie will remember that forever unless they delete the cookies from their browser, and also a script that if they click No it will remember that and not show for the remainder of that session.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wow. A LAW that says we need to ask people if it's OK to save cookies. Crazy. How about just tell people how to turn off cookies? Big Government. Sheesh! Anyway, what have you tried or researched?

Comment: Yeah I know, they say that turning off cookies in browsers isn't good enough as browsers are not sophisticated enough... 
I have tried searching lots of different ways of trying to implement this but everything I've found and tried hasn't worked as I want.
If you look at the BBC's website it'll give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve... http://www.bbc.co.uk

Comment: Somebody please help.... I've never asked for help on anything before I always research or solve the problem myself but this one is baffling me. its probably very simple, maybe I'm just over looking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
javascript.alert("By continuing to browse our site, you accept to our use of cookies.")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about doing this is below.

---

1) Create a JavaScript method that checks **if cookies are enabled** and whether **a user already accepted them**:

```
var cookieLaw = {
 setCookies : function (showCookieMsg) {
  if(navigator.cookieEnabled == true) {
   if(document.cookie.indexOf('cookie-permission') == -1) {
    showCookieMsg();
   }
  }
 },
```

2) If cookies are enabled but not accepted **a message will be displayed**:

```
 showMessage : function () {
  $('body').append('<div id="cookie-message">[your_cookie_message]<a id="continue-link" href="#">X Don't show this message again.</a></div>');
  $('#cookie-message').fadeIn();
  $('#continue-link').click(function() {
   $('#cookie-message').fadeOut();
   document.cookie = "cookie-permission=accepted; expires=Thu, 31 Jan 2030 23:59:59 UTC; path=/";
  });
 }
};
```

3) **Execute the code** when a page is ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 cookieLaw.setCookies(cookieLaw.showMessage);
};
```

4) **Make the message  invisible** by adding:

```
#cookie-message {display:none;}
```

to your CSS file and some other formatting if you require.

---

Please bear in mind that this method addresses browsers with enabled JavaScript. For non-JS browsers some server-side code would need to be added.